# Custom PreferenceDialog persistString

Tags: android, persistence, android-preferences

I'm trying to make a custom preferenceDialog which has four radioButtons, I would like to save the selected radiobutton with a diferent String and persist the value. Whe the dialog reopens, recover the string, compare and check the matched radiobutton.

I've tried persistance functions but I'm not able to achive it..

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

How about using SharedPreference to persist values?

Code Example:

```
// Gets SharedPreference with private mode
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        HARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Saves int values
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(KEY_NAME, value);
editor.commit();

// Gets int values
sharedPref.getInt(KEY_NAME, defaultValue);
```

Comment: I knew that, I was talking more about how to get checked the radiobutton at the start of the dialog

Comment: Do you use RadioGroup in your custom preferenceDialog? If so, you can get checked radio button with ID. (RadioGroup #getCheckedRadioButtonId())

Comment: I do, I think it is finally working. Thanks for your answer, was useful.

Comment: just one issue I cannot understand; I have these methods: `public ColorDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` which is my constructor; `protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder)` and `public void onBindDialogView(final View view)`; in which method should I load the saved value in order to check the radioButton??